# How do I modify my hosts file in Nixos?

Tags: hosts, nixos, nix

Seems my hosts file (`/etc/hosts`) points to `/nix/store/gds7bha3bx0a22pnzw93pgf0666anpyr-etc-hosts` and is read only.

How am I meant to modify this file?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Modify the nixos config (usually in `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`) with:

```
networking.extraHosts =
  ''
    127.0.0.2 other-localhost
    10.0.0.1 server
  '';
```

This is documented at [NixOS Wiki](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Networking) and defined [here](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/nixos/modules/config/networking.nix#L45).

Comment: It sounds like it could be an answer; perhaps Chris could use some extra words to explain what this is and why it works?

Comment: Perhaps a reference could be https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/nixos/modules/config/networking.nix#L45

Comment: When I reviewing, I thought that it looked like a fairly random piece of data.  It is clear that is has something to do with the code at the GitHub link that Jeff posted in an earlier comment, but it looks malformed (or I just don't understand the the syntax, which appears different from the GitHub code).  If this is a proper answer, please add information about where and how and why this code snipped would be used. Until then, I will still consider this to be a non-answer.  If it's a clarification to the question, then please update the question with this info and describe how it's relevant.

Comment: Well, yes, `networking.extraHosts` from the `configuration.nix` file will get into the `/etc/hosts` on the resulting NixOS system.

Comment: For future travelers, here's what the link above looked like when originally commented: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/09cbfea2edd8a525f54d96a45c0edc2fe3c94e56/nixos/modules/config/networking.nix#L45

Comment: @Kusalananda the structure at the GitHub link is what defines the option, Chris's example is how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

From Readme of [nixos-addblock-hosts](https://github.com/fps/nixos-addblock-hosts)

## nixos-addblock-hosts

A nixos configuration file that you can import from configuration.nix to block common ad/tracker hosts

Download `hosts.nix` to `/etc/nixos/hosts.nix` and add it as import to your `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` like this (example):

```
# Edit this configuration file to define what should be installed on
# your system.  Help is available in the configuration.nix(5) man page
# and in the NixOS manual (accessible by running ‘nixos-help’).

{ config, pkgs, ... }:

{
  imports =
    [ # Include the results of the hardware scan.
      ./hardware-configuration.nix
      ./hosts.nix
    ];

...
```

Also note this comment from the top of the original `hosts` file:

```
# This hosts file is brought to you by Dan Pollock and can be found at
# http://someonewhocares.org/hosts/
# You are free to copy and distribute this file for non-commercial uses,
# as long the original URL and attribution is included.
```

PLease also see [some github high level code I have no idea about](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/nixos/modules/config/networking.nix#L45), [a chat on discourse.nixos](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/how-to-edit-host-files-on-nixos-a-friendly-github-repository/16395)